# Creating an Array with the same numbers from an old one but without repetitions

Tags: java, arrays

So I created an array with random numbers, i printed and counted the repeated numbers, now I just have to create a new array with the same numbers from the first array but without any repetitions. Can't use ArrayList by the way.

What I have is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random generator = new Random();
    int aR[]= new int[20];

    for(int i=0;i<aR.length;i++){
        int number=generator.nextInt(51);
        aR[i]=number;
        System.out.print(aR[i]+" ");

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    int countRep=0;
    for(int i=0;i<aR.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<aR.length-1;j++){
            if(aR[i]==aR[j]){
                countRep++;
                System.out.println(aR[i]+" "+aR[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Repeated numbers:  "+countRep);

    int newaR[]= new int[aR.length - countRep];




}
```

Can someone help?

EDIT: Can't really use HashSet either. Also the new array needs to have the correct size.

Comment: I'm guessing that if you aren't allowed to use an `ArrayList` you can't use a `HashSet` either, right?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question to me.

Comment: What's the issue? If you're not allowed to use reasonable things like sets or hashes then it's a simple matter of nested iterations, unless the requirements also state the non-dupe array must be precisely the correct size.

Comment: yeah it needs to be the correct size

Comment: What do you need help with specifically here? Because it looks like you've started it. So is the code not working for some reason? Or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Set<Integer> insertedNumbers = new HashSet<>(newaR.length);
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < aR.length ; ++i) {
    if(!insertedNumbers.contains(aR[i])) {
        newaR[index++] = aR[i];
    }
    insertedNumbers.add(aR[i]);
}
```

Comment: is there a particular reason you reverted that edit? You definitely *don't* need to perform the contains check — HashSet does that for you already.

Comment: The reason is that a ``Set`` does not preserve the order of the original array. I agree with you that the ``HashSet`` does the check. That is actually why I use it: to make sure not to insert the same int twice while keeping the original order.

Comment: If you want to preserve the order of the original array, then just use LinkedHashSet.

Comment: Yes I could have, but he already instanciated ``newaR`` so I just wanted to show a way of adding distinct elements to it. ``LinkedHashSet`` does basically the same thing but everything is hidden :)

Comment: It's not that simple. The problem with your unmodified approach is that it requires an O(n^2) loop through the array to count the number of unique elements to size the array. If you let the Set do all of the heavy lifting (with HashSet if you don't care about order, or LinkedHashSet if you do), then it's O(n). Duplicating work to be explicit is only ok when it doesn't destroy performance...

Comment: Well I know all that. I was just completing his snippet to answer his questions. My solution is O(n), but his discovery is O(n^2) because of the loops. It could be O(n) using a simple HashSet and then O(n) for building the output array using the code I posted with an already populated set.

Comment: If you did that, it would be the edit I made to your answer, which is why I made it ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 and streams you can do the following:

```
int[] array = new int[1024];
//fill array
int[] arrayWithoutDuplicates = Arrays.stream(array)
        .distinct()
        .toArray();
```

This will:

1. Turn your `int[]` into an `IntStream`.
2. Filter out all duplicates, so retaining distinct elements.
3. Save it in a new array of type `int[]`.

Comment: This is definitely how you should do it in *production* code (as opposed to *homework* code :-D). Out of curiosity, I checked the source code, and this actually uses a LinkedHashSet under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to walk through the array, and for each value, compute the index at which it *again* occurs in the array (which is -1 if the number does not occur again). The number of values which do *not* occur again is the number of unique values. Then collect all values from the array for which the corresponding index is -1.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class UniqueIntTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int array[] = createRandomArray(20, 0, 51);
        System.out.println("Array " + Arrays.toString(array));

        int result[] = computeUnique(array);
        System.out.println("Result " + Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    private static int[] createRandomArray(int size, int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random(1);
        int array[] = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            array[i] = min + random.nextInt(max - min);
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static int[] computeUnique(int array[])
    {
        int indices[] = new int[array.length];
        int unique = computeIndices(array, indices);
        int result[] = new int[unique];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (indices[i] == -1)
            {
                result[index] = array[i];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int computeIndices(int array[], int indices[])
    {
        int unique = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            int value = array[i];
            int index = indexOf(array, value, i + 1);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                unique++;
            }
            indices[i] = index;
        }
        return unique;
    }

    private static int indexOf(int array[], int value, int offset)
    {
        for (int i = offset; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == value)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question, and if it is, the technique that you should pick up on is to sort the array first.

Once the array is sorted, duplicate entries will be adjacent to each other, so they are trivial to find:

```
int[] numbers = //obtain this however you normally would
java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers);

//find out how big the array is
int sizeWithoutDuplicates = 1; //there will be at least one entry
int lastValue = numbers[0];

//a number in the array is unique (or a first duplicate)
//if it's not equal to the number before it
for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] != lastValue) {
        lastValue = i;
        sizeWithoutDuplicates++;
    }
}

//now we know how many results we have, and we can allocate the result array
int[] result = new int[sizeWithoutDuplicates];

//fill the result array
int positionInResult = 1; //there will be at least one entry
result[0] = numbers[0];
lastValue = numbers[0];

for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] != lastValue) {
        lastValue = i;
        result[positionInResult] = i;
        positionInResult++;
    }
}

//result contains the unique numbers
```

Not being able to use a list means that we have to figure out how big the array is going to be in a separate pass — if we could use an ArrayList to collect the results we would have only needed a single loop through the array of numbers.

This approach is faster (O(n log n) vs O (n^2)) than a doubly-nested loop through the array to find duplicates. Using a HashSet would be faster still, at O(n).

Comment: If this isn't a homework question, then you should use @skiwi's answer — it's the easiest, most performant way, and there's no reason *not* to use a HashSet in real life.